# Post office inquiriy

Tags: united-kingdom, prosecution, postal-service

Following the current post office inquiry videos on YouTube ... The largest miscarriage of justice in Britain history.

Which laws are likely to have been broken.

Misleading the court/perjury seem obvious for the Fujitsu witnesses.

What possible laws were broken further up the chain, the boards, general counsel of both post office and Fujitsu?

How about the post office prosecuters/lawyers ...?

Answer (score 2):

It is not in the [Terms of Reference of the Post Office Horizon Inquiry](https://www.postofficehorizoninquiry.org.uk/publications/terms-reference) to discover potential criminal offences.

However, some may come to light as the Inquiry continues - and perhaps on its eventual conclusion.

Evidence obtained by or from the Inquiry may be used in criminal proceedings.

Reasonable inferences of potential criminal offences may also be made from the court judgments that between them have overturned 62 convictions so far.

It is confirmed that the police are investigating potential offences of

- [perjury](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/public-justice-offences-incorporating-charging-standard#_Toc536105665)
- [perverting the course of justice](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/public-justice-offences-incorporating-charging-standard#_Toc536105663)
- and [fraud](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/fraud-act-2006)

According to Metropolitan Police Commissioner Sir Mark Rowley, [it may take two years to bring criminal charges](https://news.sky.com/story/post-office-scandal-metropolitan-police-says-it-will-take-at-least-two-years-to-decide-on-criminal-charges-13050153).

> "At the core of the issue you've potentially got fraud in terms of false documents if it's for financial purposes, and you've potentially got perverting the course of justice if people have deliberately set in train evidence into a legal process, which they know is false. That would be perverting the course of justice."

There are allegations of providing false evidence and allegations of withholding potentially exculpatory evidence.

[There are also potential offences under the Inquiries Act 2005 in relation to the Inquiry itself](https://www.postofficehorizoninquiry.org.uk/further-directions-relation-late-disclosure-post-office-limited)! See [section 35](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/12/section/35).

At least one of the Fujitsu engineers is being investigated.